# ERROR 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql

I need to make a forum using PHP and MySQL. When I try to add a question in my database PhpMyAdmin return me an ERROR 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.

I'm using this request to add a question :

```
INSERT INTO questions (titre_q, text_q, date_q)  VALUES ("Help", "I'm Stuck", "2019-12-07");
```

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`vogel_forum`.`questions`, CONSTRAINT `questions_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `utilisateurs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

My database look like this :
[image]

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: in which table u inerting data ?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra sorry i forgot to add my code, i've edited my question

Comment: in question table you num_q and id field, which is primary, because issue in one of that field

Comment: if id is foreign key of utilisateurs table, then you have to pass id which present in utilisateurs

Comment: @DevsiOdedra sorry but i'm not sure to understand

Comment: i mean to say what is use of id field in questions table ?

Comment: in my questions table my id need to be the same as the utilisateurs table

Comment: so in that case when you inert in question table, you should also pass value for id field, and value for the id field shoud which exist in utilisateurs id, if does not exist in utilisateurs  id then you will get error

Comment: ok I understand my mistake ! Thank you

Comment: greate, and if you dont want to pass value then you can make default id field as null